# Magento 2: Paypal Payment Authorize Now and Capture later

Tags: magento2, payment-methods, paypal, paypal-express, magento-2.1.4

I have requirement that need to "Authorize" PayPal payment for now.

Capture/Process after X days.

On Magento side it's storing info info

```
sales_order_payment
sales_payment_transaction
```

I think need to use API, may be one of the Method

https://github.com/paypal/PayPal-PHP-SDK/tree/master/sample/payments

**magento\vendor\magento\module-paypal\Model\Express.php**

We have below methods

```
canCapture()
capture()
```

Can anybody have any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

To retrieve payment transaction details you can use Magento [REST API](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/rest/bk-rest.html).

One of the available methods is `V1/orders/{id}` (`salesOrderRepositoryV1`).

The returned order entity will contain the `last_trans_id` attribute in the `payment` node or you can use `additional_information` from `payment` node (most of the payment methods store transaction details in `additional_information`).

To capture transaction on PayPal side, you can try to use [PayPal Capture API](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/integration/direct/payments/capture-payment/) entry point.

Comment: Need more information step by step

Comment: What kind of information do you need? How to configure REST API in Magento or all solution with code?

Comment: Looking for solution with code

Comment: Big question how to get PAY-XXXXX on basis of transaction Id?